# Create Form w/ javascript and pass variable to function

Tags: javascript, forms, function, textbox

Ho can I can I create a textbox with javascript and then onclick, pass a function with argument? below the commented out line is the problem

```
var inputBox = document.createElement("input");

inputBox.staff = project.staff[j].name;
inputBox.defaultValue = inputBox.staff;
inputBox.onchange = changeHours;

//inputBox.onclick = selectText(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
inputBox.onclick=function(argument){
  selectText(this);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
inputBox.onclick=function(){selectText(this)};
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just set `onclick` with the function that you want.

```
var inputBox = document.createElement("input");

inputBox.staff = project.staff[j].name;
inputBox.defaultValue = inputBox.staff;
inputBox.onchange = changeHours;
inputBox.onclick = function() {
    selectText(this);
};
```